# ¿Cómo realizo una expresion que retorne la suma de los elementos de un vector?

Tags: array, r, matrices

¿cómo realizo una expresion que retorne la suma  de los elementos del siguiente vector?

```
x <- c(2, 1, 4, 2, 1, NA)
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/62903/4499

Comment: algoritmo: define una variable (varSuma) que contendrá la suma, luego recorre todos los elementos determinando que varSuma = elemento[indice] + varSuma. Eso sí, antes de sumar, revisa que sea un número.

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta seguramente no se respondió por que faltaba un dato importante acera del lenguaje. Pero como dice el dicho, nunca es tarde para empezar...

En `R` contamos con una función base para esto, que es justamente [`sum`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html), recibe uno o más vectores para sumar y retorna justamente el resultado. Seguramente por tu ejemplo, estás confundido por que al hacer esto:

```
> sum(x)
[1] NA
```

terminas obteniendo un "Not Available", esto ocurre porque por defecto el comportamiento es considerar los `NA` de los vectores para la suma, y `numero + NA = NA`, para solucionar esto [`sum`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html) cuenta con el parámetro `na.rm` que establece si vamos a eliminar del cálculo los valores `NA` (por defecto en `FALSE`), ahora si:

```
> sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 10
```

**Nota**: parametro como el `na.rm` hay que memorizarlo por que es muy frecuente en muchísmas funciones de `R`